# How to Send Push Notification from Xamarin Form app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center-push

Hi I am new to Xamarin forms App development. I recently set up Push Notifications through App center & Firebase. This allows me to send push notifications through their console. However Is there Library or Nuget Package By which I can send These Push notifications through .NET? i.e Send a push notification through my C# Code.
Preferably not using Web Request etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is broad question. We can't provide you exact solution. I have collected all the Proper Links these should get you Setup your App Center and your Xamarin Forms Apps. Please follow the instruction throughly.

**Configure App Center Push Server :**

As you said, You have already setup the App Center to send push notification. I hope you setup all the instruction correctly otherwise use the following link to read more in details :

iOS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/ios

Android : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android

**Configure your Forms App:**

To Setup your Xamarin forms app to receive the Push notification. Please following the following :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms

**Send/Subscribe/UnSubscribe the Push notification:**

You can call the App Center Push notification API which will send the push notification to specified Device or to the group of devices. 
Please go through the following link to learn more about App Center Push API's:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi

Let me know; If you stuck on specific problem.

Comment: How do I call Push Notification API from C#?

Comment: You're asking how to send messages over a server without using the server... that's not possible.

Comment: https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Home/post/push-notifications-with-app-center-api-integration